# How to set Content-Type for a Redirect in ASP.NET Core MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, response.redirect

I'm trying to redirect to an external page that accepts application/json content-type using

```
return RedirectPermanent(url);
```

I couldn't find a way to set the cotent-type on RedirectResult but looks like `ContentResult` could be used this way

```cs
var contentResult = new ContentResult();
contentResult.ContentType = "application/json";
contentResult.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
return contentResult;
```

How can I set the URL in the `ContentResult` or set the content-type in RedirectResult?

Comment: Content-Type is not relevant for a 3xx result that should cause client to make same request to different url

Answer (score 0):

Setting the URL on Response like this worked

```
   public ActionResult Endpoint()
   {
        Response.Redirect(url);

        var contentResult = new ContentResult();
        contentResult.ContentType = "application/json";
        contentResult.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
        return contentResult;
    }
```